# How to optimize Asp.net and Azure Storage Table for high throughput?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to optimize my asp.net website to maximize the request/sec and reduce the CPU usage.

I'm running the project on azure website VM standard 2 Core 3.5 GB ram.
A blank Page.aspx with 1000 req/sec have a 110% CPU usage.

I've added an Azure Table storage that insert a new Row at each pageload.

Model:

```
public class ClicksAzureTableEntity : TableEntity
{
    public void setKeys(DateTime dt, string clickId)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = clickId;
        this.RowKey = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clickId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

    var entity = new ClicksAzureTableEntity();
    entity.setKeys(DateTime.UtcNow,clickId);

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PerformanceTableConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Clicks");
    TableOperation insertOrReplaceOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
    // Execute the operation.
     table.Execute(insertOrReplaceOperation);
}
```

With this code the performance degradate really fast:

For 200ms response time the maximum request are 200/sec

In `global.asax` I've tried to optimize changing the MinThread or Disabling Nagle without success.

```
    workerThreads = 4;//2 * number of processor as suggested in documentation

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreads, currentMinIOC)

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

If I horizontal scale to 2 VM req for sec are 400. But I still think that performance are really poor and this kind of VM should manage up to 2000 req per sec. I've also noticed that CPU usage is really high, around 1% for request.

**UPDATE**:
Async pattern

```
  public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
  }

  public async Task LoadSomeData()
  {
   clickId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

    var entity = new ClicksAzureTableEntity();
    entity.setKeys(DateTime.UtcNow,clickId);

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PerformanceTableConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Clicks");
    TableOperation insertOrReplaceOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
    // Execute the operation.
     await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOrReplaceOperation);
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**
Seems that async pattern use more Memory and CPU than sync pattern. I'm actually having better performance with sync pattern. Any reason why? Maybe it could be asp.net configuration or wrong using of async/await?

I've also Tested the SAS token generated directly on the azure portal.
note: when you generate the Token set the start day few days before the current day to avoid any client time mismatch due timezone.

```
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials("?sv=2017-04-1*******");

    CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri("https://******.table.core.windows.net/"), creds);
```

With this edit we have a great performance improving, moving from 200 req to 300 req per seconds.

But we are still far from thousands of req per secosnds as i sould expect from this kind of VM.

Comment: `table.Execute` is a sync method. Try changing it to `table.ExecuteAsync` and see if that results in any improvement.

Comment: @GauravMantri already tested table.ExecuteAsync. unfortunately i didn't have better performance with current configuration. Load test was less linear and response time was less stable.

Comment: I agree with Gaurav. You could optimize CPU by using SAS credentials, but as long as you're blocking your worker threads on the network you'll be limiting your scalability. Could you update the question to use the async pattern?

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT i've already updated the question with await async pattern

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT i still have same performance with async. How can i use SAS credential. Do you have any snippet?